# Error sound when I'm setting manually the cursor manually in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm a beginner with C # and I made the following GUI (see Screenshot). There, the idea is for the user to enter an ID. Then, the user presses enter and the cursor is automatically positioned in the cell with the red square. At this moment the program is working correctly. However, when the cursor is moved from the text box to the datagrid view, a sound is heard as if it were an error.

[image]

Therefore I would like to eliminate this sound, the code I use is presented below. I would appreciate if someone could help me

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        dataGridView1_Konfiguration();
        //txtPerson => ID texteditor
        txtPerson.Focus();
        txtPerson.SelectionStart = txtPerson.Text.Length;

}

private void txtPerson_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e){

        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)){    
                e.Handled = true;
        }
}


private void txtPerson_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && txtPerson.Text == ""){

           MessageBox.Show("Bitte geben ein gültige Personalnummer !!");
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && txtPerson.Text != ""){

           dataGridView1.Enabled = true;
           dataGridView1.Focus();
           dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mi question is not how to set mouse cursor position because it is working!!!  why I have this sound, please read the description of the problem before!!

Comment: Do you know at which point in code the sound occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an empty WinForms project with just a TextBox and nothing else you will still get this sound when you press enter. I think this has to do with the Form.AcceptButton property and where the event gets routed, but I am not sure.

In your case, to remove the sound, you can just supress further handling of the input event after you switched to the cell. You can just put this

```
 e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
```

inside your txtPerson_KeyDown handler.

The entire code snippet would turn out something like this:

```
    private void txtPerson_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && txtPerson.Text == "")
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Bitte geben ein gültige Personalnummer !!");
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && txtPerson.Text != "")
        {

            dataGridView1.Enabled = true;
            dataGridView1.Focus();
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Selected = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

I hope that helps!